# Overlaying Html Content on top of Silverlight App

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, windowless

I have a silverlight application that I am embedding in an existing ASP.NET web application. The web application has several drop-down navigation menus that would normally cover part of the silverlight app. I am aware of embedding the app using "windowless" mode, and if I do so the HTML menus show up on top of the silverlight plugin and everything looks great.

The problem is that I do not want to run in windowless mode due to its limitations. The application needs to handle MouseWheel events, which are not available natively in windowless mode. I am also not happy with the performance drawbacks of running in windowless mode. If I set windowless mode to false, the silverlight plugin is always rendered on top of the navigation menus which drop down behind it.

Is there any kind of CSS/JavaScript/Z-Index hackery that can be done to force certain divs of HTML on my page to render on top of the silverlight app *WITHOUT* running in windowless mode? I don't have high hopes as I understand this scenario is one of the main reasons for running in windowless mode, but I figured I'd ask and see if there are any workaround ideas.

Comment: I've come to terms with the fact that this probably isn't possible. I can redo my MouseWheel handling by attaching to DOM events so it will work in windowless mode instead of the native support. However, my main concern is performance if my application is playing video with several MediaElements. I've heard that running in windowless mode is not good for performance, but does anyone know any info about just *how* bad it is? How much more performant would a silverlight app streaming several MediaElements be if it were not running in windowless mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that if you want to do any kind of overlaying of HTML over silverlight, you **HAVE** to use windowless mode. From what I understand this really is the main point of running in windowless mode, and no CSS hack is really going to solve this issue.

Comment: I've discovered that there is actually an iframe cutout hack in most browsers that can be used to mask windowed plugin content (like Silverlight and Flash) so you can overlay HTML on top. More info here: http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/notes/2009/07/windowed-windowless-plugins.html

Answer (score -1):

To do this just set windowsless param to true

src:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/05/10/integrating-html-into-silverlight-applications.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Sharepoint menus seem to hover over silverlight and flash elements without setting the wmode or windowless parameters.  If someone can determine how sharepoint does it then there we have it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This doesn't seems an Answer, it looks like a Question.